# How to avoid resource contentions for std::future.wait_for and std::thread::sleep_for?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, race-condition

I am facing a hang issue due to long wait for future.wait_for

```
 while ((future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50))) != std::future_status::ready)
 {
     sendHeartBeat()
 }
```

This is the hang stack:

```
Count:48|(0xb8d8ed)std::condition_variable::wait_for<__int64,std::ratio<1,1000>,std::_Associated_state<int>::_Test_ready>+0x19d
Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\include\mutex:627+0x174

    Count:38|MSVCP140.dll - 0x12e03 - _Cnd_timedwait
    Count:38|MSVCP140.dll - 0x12c55 - ?_Winerror_message@std@@YAKKPEADK@Z
    Count:29|KERNELBASE.dll - 0x6dc69 - SleepConditionVariableSRW
    Count:23|KERNELBASE.dll - 0x730e9 - SleepConditionVariableSRW
    Count:8|KERNELBASE.dll - 0x76339 - SleepConditionVariableSRW
    Count:2|KERNELBASE.dll - 0x6d059 - SleepConditionVariableSRW
    Count:1|KERNELBASE.dll - 0x76b99 - SleepConditionVariableSRW
    Count:10|MSVCP140.dll - 0x12d83 - _Cnd_timedwait
    Count:10|MSVCP140.dll - 0x12bd5 - ?_Winerror_message@std@@YAKKPEADK@Z
```

Comment: Please provide more details and a [mre] for your problem. Is your problem that you wait too long or that you hang (forever)? What is `future` and what is `sendHeartBeat`? What is the resource contention in this case? Where does `sleep_for` enter the picture?

Comment: future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50) waits for too long(much more than 50milliseconds) which moves my application in hang state.

As per CPPReference docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for
It mentions that : 
This function may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

Looks like my code is waiting for much more than the given timeout.

Comment: `wait_for` can wait a bit longer depending on OS, but the number is insignificant. On linux, it is up to 10ms while on windows there is a method to control the time period, with 1ms minimum. Ofcourse, if your PC is 100% busy, it can take longer as well. Though, in your case I believe you have a problem elsewhere. Perhaps, UB like data race elsewhere.

Comment: @ManojHanamshet How much longer? What accuracy are you expecting here? Also, is your system under heavy load? If so any delays can obviously become arbitrarily long anyway (at least on a non-realtime system and/or without realtime scheduler priority).

Comment: @user17732522 watchdog is set to 8-10 seconds. If I don't send heartbeat from here within that much time, it will be treated as hang.

Comment: @ALX23z may be but not sure, as I don's see in the current stack any race conditions. but as you said it's possible. and more over this is happening on my clients computer where I don't have much information about system was 100%busy. is there any other way to debug or avoid this situation?

Comment: @ManojHanamshet could it be that Client's PC simply goes to sleep? Your processes will be suspended during it.

Comment: @ALX23z, yes it's possible. The system might be put to sleep and then resume.

Comment: But then wouldn't the watchdog assume that "HeartBeat" wasn't sent for too long upon resuming?

Comment: Yes it might assume. When a system goes to sleep while a wait_for function is being executed, the thread executing the wait_for function will be suspended until the system wakes up again. Once the system resumes, the wait_for function will continue executing normally. isn't it?